# How do I convert an existing folder into a Document Set?

Tags: 2010, document-library, folder, document-set, conversion

So I have read all over the place that it is possible to convert an existing SharePoint 2010 folder to a Document set. There is apparently even a tool to make sure that this goes smoothly ([SharePoint 2010 Folder To Document Set Conversion Fix](http://foldertodocsetfix.codeplex.com/)). The problem is that I cannot find anything explaining how to actually make this conversion happen. I have read somewhere that you need to add the document set content type to the library but I don't know what to do from there.

Can anyone give me a quick walk-through on how to convert an existing SharePoint folder into a document set?

Comment: check this one http://sharedpointers.blogspot.com/2013/04/fixing-folders-that-have-been-converted.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this. But I believe you need to deploy the sandbox solution to your site collection and activate it.

Once this is done you can open the folder property and change the content type to Document Set. <- This will work for future folders but not existing ones.

The workflow mentioned in the link bellow will do the trick. 
Also take a look at this link

https://sharepointdojo.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/turn-folders-into-document-sets-yup/

**Update**

1. Add Document Set Content Type to the library
2. Now Edit Properties of any folder. You can see the Content Type drop down. Select "Document Set" and save.

[image]

Comment: Yep just saw that... Feeling kinda blind hehe

Answer (score 0):

Use [Set-PnPListItem](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Set-PnPListItem.html):

```
Set-PnPListItem -List "List Name" -Identity [ItemId] -ContentType "Document Set"
```